# GroupBox size doesn't change in the run time?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

As you can see when I change the GroupBox size, it doesn't change in the run time, it'll stay like its first status, what's wrong?

Comment: Is something changed in the Anchor-property? Wich window shows what?

Comment: No I just used background color, and font color.
Main Form.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the maximum and mininum size of the groupbox is set to **0;0**

Then you probably need to anchor the groupbox:

[image]

Anchor the groupbox to the right.